# How to execute mongodb sql in the shell when it appear "..."?

Tags: mongodb

when I try to execute:

```
>db.analytics.update({"name":"king"},{"$inc":{"pageview":1}
```

and click `enter`

it shows:

```
> db.analytics.update({"name":"king"},{"$inc":{"pageview":1})
... 
...
```

what should I do to execute this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it appears when you have syntax errors and your expression is not closed properly. Here you're missing two brackets on the end. Try:

```
db.analytics.update({"name":"king"},{"$inc":{"pageview":1}})
```